# loop synchronously through array while calling asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

My problem: i have an array with users and an user_hash and need to find the matching user. I came up with the following solution:

```
//results is the array user objects
//safety_first.getUserHash is a function that calculates a user_hash, it retrieves the user-record based on the id and then combines values of some fields and a key and turns this into a hash.
if (results.length > 0)
    {
      var i = 0;
      function checkUserhash(user_id, user_hash, callback) {
        safety_first.getUserHash(user_id, function(check_user_hash) {
          if (user_hash == check_user_hash)
          {
            callback(user_id);
          }
          else
          {
            if ((i+1) < results.length)
            {
              i++;
              checkUserhash(results[i].id, user_hash, callback);
            }
            else
            {
              callback(false);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      checkUserhash(results[i].id, user_hash, function(user_id) {
        if (user_id)
        {
          console.log("MATCH: "+user_id);
        }
        else
        {
          console.log("NO MATCH");
        }
      });


    }
```

I first tried to do this in a for-loop but cause it calls the checkUserhash asychronously i could not break the loop when the match was found.

I'm looking for other possible solutions, please share your thoughts.

regards, Pieter

Comment: Is `safety_first` a service you could change? E.g. return a promise instead of using a callback?

Answer (score 2):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your user array to create an array of promises. Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for those promises to resolve and then iterate over the responses to check whether the hash matches the id.

In this example I've used [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). I've also mocked up a hashing function routine so you can see it in action. Simply change the resolve from 'id' to 'id + 1' and rerun the demo to see the `Match`  become `No match`.

Hope this is some use.

```js
const safety_first = {
  getUserHash(id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(id), 1000);
    });
  }
}

async function checkUserHashes(userList, promises) {
  try {

    // await the promises to all resolve
    // `Promise.all` preserves the order...
    const res = await Promise.all(promises);

    // ...which makes it useful if you need to check the returned
    // results against the promise-producing array
    userList.forEach(({ id }, i) => {
      if (id === res[i]) console.log(`${id}|${res[i]} - Match`);
      if (id !== res[i]) console.log(`${id}|${res[i]} - No match`);
    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const userList = [{ id: 1, userHash: 1 }, { id: 2, userHash: 2 }];

// `map` over the fields and return a
// validation promise for each
const promises = userList.map(({ id }) => {
  return safety_first.getUserHash(id);
});

// Pass in the original userList, and the generated promises
checkUserHashes(userList, promises);
```

Update: if you want to break out of the loop when a match has been found that's a little easier:

```js
const safety_first = {
  getUserHash(id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

      // This will match the second object (index 1)
      setTimeout(() => resolve(id === 1 ? id: id + 1), 1000);
    });
  }
}

async function checkUserHashes(userList) {

  // iterate over the array of objects
  for (let [index, obj] of userList.entries()) {

    // await for that one hash check
    const res = await safety_first.getUserHash(obj.id);

    // if it matches return the id
    if (obj.id === res) return obj;
  }

  // otherwise return null if there are no matches
  return null;
}

const userList = [{ id: 0, userHash: 1 }, { id: 1, userHash: 2 }];

(async () => {
  const id = await checkUserHashes(userList);
  console.log(id);
})();
```

Comment: With this solution hashes are generated for all users in my result list, right? I'm looking for a solution where i can generate one user hash, check it, not good then the next one. So that when i have 4000 users and i find the right one after 5 loops, the program wil break out the loop.

Comment: Updated the answer @Overbeeke.